# Hypothetical: storing date-time data with varying specificity in SQL Server for .NET MVC app

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, date

I've got five .NET classes and corresponding SQL Server tables, each with a start and and end date, and I may have to store the dates with varying degrees of specificity, e.g., 2005, 04/2005, or 04/01/2005.  That is, I might have to store the day, month, and year; the month and year; or just the year.

What is the best way to do that?  The way I'm going to use (because of time constraints) is to add an enum to my application for the specificity, add a column/property for the specificity to each class/table, and store the value as the earliest date within the value, e.g., 04/01/2005 if the user provides 04/2005. I'm using NHibernate, but the question for me is mostly about the database.

I'd like to know, since I'm sure I'll have to do this again, and I'd like to have a better solution, perhaps something using CLR user-defined types?

Thanks!

edit: I ended up doing something more like in the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having three nullable columns of data type SMALLINT fot the year and TINYINT for month and day seems to be the easiest solution. If you need an index you can put it on Year ASC, Month ASC, Day ASC. You can use SQL Servers DATEPART function to convert from a date value to your values.

The type of this special date you could get with a query like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Month IS NULL THEN 'YearOnly'
            WHEN Day IS NULL THEN 'YearMonth'
            ELSE 'FullDate'
       END AS SpecialDateType
  FROM dbo.yourtable;
```

You could wrap this all in a CLR datatype, but I am not sure it is worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ended up doing something similar to this where I , but instead of using the specificity indicator, I built up a DATE using a computed column for sorting that assume the first January 1 if there is month and the first of the month if there is no day.  The real part of my question was about the three individual parts, and I like your way better than my original proposal.

Answer (score 0):

I think that storing the values as dates makes sense because it will make querying simple. I don't see a need for an enum to declare the specificity. I would model the properties with backing fields and control resolution through the public getter/setter:

```
private DateTime _theDate;

public DateTime TheDate
{
    get { return _theDate; }
    set { _theDate = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, 1); }
    // or use a utility class _theDate = DateUtils.MonthResolution(value);
}
```